# Loop over array of objects, remove duplicates, take one out and assign boolean to original

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have the following sample arr:

```
const fetchedArr = [
{ id: "3cc74658-a984-4227-98b0-8c28daf7d3d4", type: a },
{ id: "9b96e055-dc2a-418c-9f96-ef449e34db60", type: a },
{ id: "9b96e055-dc2a-418c-9f96-ef449e34db60", type: b }
]
```

i need the following output :

```
const arr = [
{ id: "3cc74658-a984-4227-98b0-8c28daf7d3d4", type: a, checked: true },
{ id: "9b96e055-dc2a-418c-9f96-ef449e34db60", type: a, checked: true, hasPair: true }
]
```

I have the following snippet which works

```
 const newLegendItems = fetchedArr
      .reduce((acc, curr, idx, arr) => {
        const singleComponentLines = arr.filter((g) => g.id === curr.id);
        const exists = !!acc.find((x) => x.id === curr.id);
        if (!exists) {
          if (singleComponentLines.length === 2 && singleComponentLines.includes(curr)) {
            acc[idx] = {...curr, hasPair: true};
          } else {
            acc[idx] = curr;
          }
        }
        return acc;
      }, [])
      .map((l) => ({ ...l, checked: true }));
```

, but i was thinking if there's simpler way to achieve this?
I should clarify that in the `fetchedArr`, the `type` does not matter, and that there won't be more than two same Id's, hence my idea for `singleComponentLines.length === 2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```js
const fetchedArr = [
{ id: "3cc74658-a984-4227-98b0-8c28daf7d3d4", type: "a" },
{ id: "9b96e055-dc2a-418c-9f96-ef449e34db60", type: "a" },
{ id: "9b96e055-dc2a-418c-9f96-ef449e34db60", type: "b" }
];

let result = fetchedArr.reduce((acc,v) => {
   //first i need to check if i already have an element with the same ID in my accumulator. i either get -1 for not found or the index where the element is.
   let i = acc.findIndex(el => el.id === v.id);
   
   if(i !== -1) {
      //if there is an element then access the element in the array with a[i] and add a new property to the object with ["hasPair"] and set it to true
      acc[i]["hasPair"] = true;
      
      return acc;
   }

   //in case i = -1 what means not found
   return [...acc, {...v, checked: true}];
},[])

console.log(result);
```

Comment: very cool answer ....would you mind a bit of explaination please ..

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your question but it should help:

```js
const result = [{
    id: "3cc74658-a984-4227-98b0-8c28daf7d3d4",
    type: 'a'
  },
  {
    id: "9b96e055-dc2a-418c-9f96-ef449e34db60",
    type: 'a'
  },
  {
    id: "9b96e055-dc2a-418c-9f96-ef449e34db60",
    type: 'b'
  }
].reduce((acc, el) => {
  const idx = acc.findIndex(it => it.id === el.id);
  if (idx > -1) {
    acc[idx] = { ...acc[idx],
      hasPair: true
    }
  } else {
    acc.push({ ...el,
      checked: true
    });
  }

  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I rather use a Map for this kind of things since it brings more readability IMO.

1. Start by checking if we already have it
2. Update our component and add it to the Map

The only "tricky" thing is that we need to iterate over `.values()` to grab our updated components, but thanks to [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) it's quite easy.

```js
const components = [
  { id: "3cc74658-a984-4227-98b0-8c28daf7d3d4", type: 'a' },
  { id: "9b96e055-dc2a-418c-9f96-ef449e34db60", type: 'a' },
  { id: "9b96e055-dc2a-418c-9f96-ef449e34db60", type: 'b' },
];

const newLegendItems = components
  .reduce((acc, component) => {
    if (acc.has(component.id)) {
      acc.get(component.id)['hasPair'] = true;
    } else {
      acc.set(component.id, { ...component, checked: true });
    }

    return acc;
  }, new Map());
  
  console.log([...newLegendItems.values()]);
```